# Expandablelistview is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

i am trying to do Expandablelistview. But its not expanding the parent view..

this is the first time i am trying to do Expandablelistview. Please help me to solve this mistake.

expand is not working when i onclick of parent. how to do it.

below is my code

```
          public class WorkDetailView extends Activity { 
private ListView listviewDialog;
private ExpandableListView detaillistView;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detaillistview);


     detaillistView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.detailListview);
    detaillistView.setDividerHeight(1);
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    detaillistView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(40), width - GetDipsFromPixel(5));
    dataAdapter = new WorkDetailAdapter(WorkDetailView.this, sampleDetailsArray);
    detaillistView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


      public int GetDipsFromPixel(float pixels)
    {
     // Get the screen's density scale
     final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
     // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
     return (int) (pixels * scale + 20f);
    }

         }



       public class WorkDetailAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<PatientSampleDetails> sampleDetailsArray; 

public WorkDetailAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<PatientSampleDetails> sampleDetailsArray) {
        this.sampleDetailsArray = sampleDetailsArray;
        this.activity = activity;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);      
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater) {
          this.minflater = mInflater;
         }
           static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView1;

    private TextView volumetext, textViewDateTime, textViewOrderNo;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return sampleDetailsArray.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(); 
         if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detaillistrowview, null);


    }
                convertView.setTag(holder); 



            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return sampleDetailsArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return sampleDetailsArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return sampleDetailsArray.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(); 
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.getgroupviewdetail, null);
        }
            CheckBox  checkBoxGroup = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxGroup);
            checkBoxGroup.setChecked(true);
            holder.textViewOrderNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOrderNo);



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Log.i("eeeeeeeeeee", "click");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/lalit3686/ExandableListViewDemo

Comment: @dokkaebi s it show only parent data. when i click its not expanding

Comment: Try [adding an `OnGroupClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnGroupClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener)) and see if it's called. As a side note, I see some problems with your ViewHolders. Move `new ViewHolder` and `setTag(holder)` inside the if blocks, and add `ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()` after the if blocks.

Answer (score 1):

here [example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/) of Exapndable listview.. refer it.

try this [demo](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=28652&s=a5fc64500c422342c93165b0c38c2710)

Comment: just check i have added on creat now